# Boot Windows From SSD

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, multi-boot, grub

I recently system cloned my windows 10 via ease us backup to ssd. It showed that drive as A in windows. I am not getting option in bios to boot via ssd. I have linux dual booted, so I ran sudo grub-install and update so It started detecting two Windows boot managers, one on ssd and other one on hdd. But now whether I boot from hdd or ssd. I always boots from hdd. i got to know this from speed, and in taskmanager performance always hdd is being used on loads and ssd active time is 0, and in drives section, HDD is mounted as C and my ssd shows as A always whether I boot from hdd or ssd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only ever have one drive connected (the ssd in your case) when you first install windows .

Otherwise you can end up with the actual windows install on the ssd but the boot partition on the other drive.

Which sounds like exactly what's happened

The fix? - physically disconnect the secondary drive & reinstall windows on the ssd from scratch.

Alternatively though I’ve never tested it, apparently this also works:

Type msconfig into Start Menu search bar to open System Configuration.  From the Boot tab select Windows 10 entry and click Set as default button.
 
Mark the Windows 10 partition active as the partition then try to delete the Windows partition.

(It should work and I see no reason it wouldn’t,I just can’t vouch for it as I’ve never done it)